# Calculating Moran's I on large point dataframe in R

Tags: r, point, spatial-statistics, autocorrelation

I have a dataset of about 77,000 points of which I want to test autocorrelation. I have tried to compute the test statistic using the [testSpatialAutocorrelation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/DHARMa/versions/0.1.3/topics/testSpatialAutocorrelation) tool in the [DHARMa package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/DHARMa.pdf), which uses "a simulation-based approach to create readily interpretable scaled (quantile) residuals for fitted (generalized) linear mixed models." However when I try to run the test, I run into a memory error. What is a way to easily calculate Moran's I for a large dataset?

Comment: Tried `moran` from `spdep`, which computes Moran's I and nothing much else? What's your adjacency list like?

Comment: What datatype and values you use as weigths?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this same problem.  I created an R package that calculates the distance matrix on the fly, so it takes much less memory to calculate Moran's I.  Its also quite fast.  You can find it at github.com/mcooper/moranfast.

Comment: This looks interesting! Thanks for answering an old question. I'll see if this runs well with my data.

Comment: This worked pretty well. Less than a minute on a 70,000 point dataset and about 5-6 minutes for a 300,000 dataset.